# Integrate ViewerJS in Lotus Domino

Tags: lotus-domino, pdfviewer

Any idea of how to integrate [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/) into Lotus Domino?

I tried to deploy *ViewerJS* folder into *html* directory on server, but without success.

Comment: Trying to follow the instructions, I obtain this: **Http Status Code: 403

Reason: Unable to process request, directory browsing is not allowed**

Comment: What did you use as the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i forgot to specify

*index.html*

in URL.

I type something like

```
http://<server>/ViewerJS/#../<dbpath>/0/576B03A3CD9F0180C1257C860037F2B5/$FILE/doc.pdf
```

instead of

```
http://<server>/ViewerJS/index.html#../<dbpath>/0/576B03A3CD9F0180C1257C860037F2B5/$FILE/doc.pdf
```

In this case seems to work