# Acrobat IE plugin hang when open remote PDF

Tags: pdf, lotus-domino, acrobat, freeze

Hang problems still experienced if I try to open pdf using remote url (i.e. `http://<server>/<dbpath>/0/$FILE/file.pdf`).

Acrobat Reader version: **11.0.09**

Even if I use another [viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188208/integrate-viewerjs-in-lotus-domino) the hang problem still remains. Could be a PDF file problem? What to investigate?

Comment: Does it happen for all PDF files? Or just one. If it is all, is there something in common for all those PDFs? (I.e., are they generated the same way? Are they all attached to the documents by the same process? Etc.)

Comment: They are attachments of e-mail in a mail database

Comment: This e-mail is downloaded directly into a mail DB through http://www.fetchmail.info/